# Наследник и родитель

Tags: ооп, java

Привет.

Есть абстрактный класс BinaryNum  с методом and. Есть классы Int32, StringNum - наследники класса BinaryNum.

```
BinaryNum b1 = new Int32();
BinaryNum b2 = new StringNum();

b1.and();
b2.and()
```

Как мне в методе and создать новый обьект класса Int32 или StringNum. Т.е. мне нужно создать обьект класса, который вызвал метод. Это возможно?

Comment: Метод and() абстрактный?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего без рефлексии здесь не обойтись...

Если у вас классы-наследники, как описано в примере, имеют конструкторы по умолчанию, без аргументов, тогда можно создать объект необходимого типа через метод newInstance():

```
public void and() {
    try {
        BinaryNum newObj = this.getClass().newInstance();
        ...
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

По-хорошему, родительский класс не должен знать о дочерних. Переопределите метод `and` в дочерних классах с нужной реализацией.